# is there a way to autheticate a user using saml from a desktop browser in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, openid-connect, saml

i am trying to create a javafx application has a button when clicked, opens the user's web browser and authenticates the person using SAML after which the user is redirected back to the application with authorization code. if valid verification, the user is granted access to more scenes. Now i understand using saml in java desktop is difficult. however if any other alternative is available i'll like to have it and also a tutorial or sample on how to go about its usage

Comment: Please provide more details. Like what you have tried so far, what's blocking you, etc.x

Comment: in overall, i tried saml. but that didn't go anywhere, i just need any suggestion on alternative or ways to go about it using any authentication tool like OPENID connect, SAML, OAuth. perhaps a tutorial video or article or document.